# C++: Why the whole string is not getting printed?

Tags: c++, string

Windows 7, 32 bit ,  MSVS 2010

My understanding is that when you do :

```
char szString[100] = "string";
```

compiler will expect 101 char spaces.  OS will then allocate this 101 char space in RAM.

Now I am putting 7 characters (including null) in szString, but the total size of szString is 100. So I am expecting that printing szString should result in `string` plus 93 garbage values taken from location szString[7] to szString[99]. But cout is not behaving this way.  it only prints `string`

What is the mechanism then?   Is my understanding wrong?

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

char szString[100] = "string";
cout << szString;

    return 0; 
}
```

**output**

```
string
```

Comment: The whole string is being printed. The character buffer contains a six-character string, a nul terminator, and then a bunch of junk that was never initialized.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz What is "bunch of junk " ? Some values ? But we never initialize values, right ? we initialize memory locations. Am I right ?   And if the buffer has all those junk, why is it not reaching the console  ? (I thought buffer only has values till NULL, and then this buffer is printed by cout)

Comment: The junk is after the string. You asked `cout` to print the string, and it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`So I am expecting that printing szString should result in string plus 93 garbage values taken from location szString[7] to szString[99].`

That is a wrong assumption. A string is an array of characters which is null terminated by <kbd>\0</kbd>, called NUL in ASCII.

Try to print the last 2 values:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    using namespace std;

    char szString[100] = "string";
    int len1 = szString[5], len2 = szString[6];
    cout << len1 << endl;
    cout << len2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

We get the ascii values 103 and 0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  How much memory OS will allocate ? 7 or 101?

Comment: @user3891236 - `101` however only the length of string plus the `nul` character is what is being used.

Comment: why it is so? Is it defines in the C++ standard, that cout will behave like that?

Comment: The behavior is how string works - cout prints till the nul terminator.

Answer (score 1):

There is a short article on it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/), but to briefly explain:

A string literal represented in a character sequence, (such as `"string"`) is by convention **null terminating**, meaning that on creation an `\0` (or null character) is added onto the end of the string.

This means that this line

```
char szString[100] = "string";
```

Is automatically appended to

```
char szString[100] = "string\0";
```

This is also why a (narrow) string literal is one byte larger than the number of characters it holds: The extra byte is taken up by a `\0`, indicating the end of the string.

`std::cout` will ignore all data after a null character in a `char` array like szString, so the resulting output is simply "`string`".